# Turkish character problems json encode - Mysql

Tags: mysql

I output with the json_encode method. It does not show Turkish characters in the output I have received. What should I do to show Turkish characters? I am using mysql. Collation of the table = utf8_turkish_ci

[image: output]

```
<?php
 $con=mysqli_connect(...);
  header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);
$formID = $_POST['formID'];
     $query = "SELECT ADI_SOYADI ...";

     $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

     $rows = array();
     while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
         $apptADI = $r['ADI_SOYADI'];
         $results = Array("ADI_SOYADI" => $apptADI);
     }

     echo json_encode($results);

     mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that prior to use `json_encode()`you should use `utf8_encode()`

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/php-utf8_encode-function/

```
 echo json_encode(utf8_encode($results));
```

There is also the parameter `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` that  you can add to `json_encode()`

Comment: I am outputting a null value